# Renombrar directorio linux

Tags: linux, bash

Buenas os expongo el pequeño problema que tengo, he actualziado un tema en wordpress y el antiguo le he cambiado el nombre, al directorio le he puesto .old al final, pero asi ahora no puedo acceder.

He intentado renombrarlo otra vez con -old al final pero no me deja utilizar el comando mv "no such file or directory

```
 mv theme theme.old


 mv theme.old theme-old 

  " mv: cannot stat theme.old: No such file or directory "
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @MiguelEspeso lo estoy haciendo como root

Comment: Perdona, si lo que te dice es que ni existe el directorio

Comment: Puedes probar con: **mv 'theme.old' theme-old**. Al tener el . debes indicar que se trata de una cadena literal. Te pasaría lo mismo con un nombre con espacios en medio.

Comment: @PHPMyguel Buenas, mismo problema "no such file or directory".

Comment: Prueba escapando el punto con: **mv theme\.old theme-old**.

Comment: el problema persiste

Comment: En el directorio donde estas haciendo el `mv` tiene solo cuatro directorios. Y el unico que acaba en .old es `dt-the7.old` y no `theme.old`. Si he entendido bien tu problema, debes ejecutar `mv dt-the7.old theme-old`

Comment: No lo que pasa que aqui dije theme.old antes de subir la captura el nombre del archivo es dt-th7.old lo intento pasar a dt-th-old pero persiste el error comentado siempre

Comment: actualiza la captura de pantalla. Segun la que tienes ahora el nombre actual con old es `dt-the7.old` (con una `e`)

Comment: @Jakala si perdona es el correcto dt-the7.old es el que tengo y quiero cambiar

Comment: ok. Si te da problemas por el nombre, puedes utilizar la tecla `tab` de tu teclado para escribir el directorio completo. escribe `mv dt-` y a continuacion pulsa la tecla `tab`. Esto deberia completar el nombre de tu carpeta. luego deja un espacio y pon el nombre que quieras poner.

Comment: Intenta con cp -r origen destino

Comment: @JackNavaRow Gracias!! Asi funcionó :)

Comment: El error seguramente se deba a que existe la carpeta `theme-old` pero no tengas permisos de lectura en la misma, puedes verificarlo, siempre con el mismo usuario, haciendo ` ls theme-old` , debería darte un error similar.

Answer (score 3):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes una errata:

El fichero se llama dt-th**e**7.old

estás intentando renombrar un fichero llamado dt-th7.old (sin la e)

Demostración en mi PC:

```
pablo@Pablo-asus:~/temp$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  2 pablo pablo 4096 dic  5 10:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 47 pablo pablo 4096 dic  4 15:43 ../
-rw-------  1 pablo pablo   66 oct  2 18:01 .directory

pablo@Pablo-asus:~/temp$ mkdir dt-the7.old
pablo@Pablo-asus:~/temp$ ll
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  3 pablo pablo 4096 dic  5 10:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 47 pablo pablo 4096 dic  4 15:43 ../
-rw-------  1 pablo pablo   66 oct  2 18:01 .directory
drwxrwxr-x  2 pablo pablo 4096 dic  5 10:48 dt-the7.old/

pablo@Pablo-asus:~/temp$ mv dt-the7.old/ dtheme
pablo@Pablo-asus:~/temp$ ll
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  3 pablo pablo 4096 dic  5 10:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 47 pablo pablo 4096 dic  4 15:43 ../
-rw-------  1 pablo pablo   66 oct  2 18:01 .directory
drwxrwxr-x  2 pablo pablo 4096 dic  5 10:48 dtheme/
```

Con mv debería funcionar perfectamente

Comment: Buenas pablo como ya he comentado arriba, soy consciente que lo he puesto mal el archivo se ha llamado en todo momento dt-the7.old no estoy intentando renombrar un archivo escribiendo mal su nombre. Me hubiera dado cuenta y no estaria aqui preguntando. Y segundo @jackNavaRow me dio la solucion

Comment: @Caldeiro A menudo no nos damos cuenta de las erratas y tras probar algo escribimos bien el nombre. La solución de @JackNavaRow funcionó, pero realmente `mv`debería haberte funcionado

Comment: Tienes razón disculpa

Answer (score 1):

Como sugerencia para evitar que te vuelva a pasar (y como momento oportuno para mostrar lo bonitos que son estos programas). Cuando escribas `mv`, o algún otro comando, presiona la tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd> para que se active la función de auto-completar (ver [*Programmable Completion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion)), si te dice que no está es porque no está ... ese nombre (o aparenta no estarlo). El auto-completado te ayuda a prevenir errores tipográficos y a evitar el tedio de escribir nombres raros o fastidiosos.

Si quieres una ayuda más gráfica, instala alguna shell más amigable como `zsh` o `fish` y te va a permitir elegir de los archivos de forma colorida y más precisa, verbosa e informativa.

#### Con Z shell (zsh)

http://www.zsh.org/ (Recomiendo ampliamente https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Con Fish

https://fishshell.com/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ambos efectos se dieron al darle <kbd>Tab</kbd> después de la cadena `ls`

Ahora, esto no es para hacerte la vida más fácil. Esperaría que fueran para aumentar nuestra productividad, no para parchar imprecisiones técnicas. Digo, si cosas como estas pasan, primero hay que cuidar los pasos que hicimos, revisar cuidadosamente el resultado del `ls`, `mv`, etc., y su auto completado (con <kbd>Tab</kbd>), y tratar de entender el "por qué" de los mensajes de error.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte